# How to resolve Django Error in formatting: AttributeError: 'Habit' object has no attribute 'goal'

Tags: python, django

I runserver to test my Habit Tracker app. Not sure why I get Error in formatting: AttributeError: 'Habit' object has no attribute 'goal'. Have included my models.py. I need your help understanding what I have written incorrectly and how to fix the code. thank you.

```
class Habit(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    goal_nbr = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    goal_description = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=True, blank=True)
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, related_name="habit", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    @property
    def duration(self):
        delta = end_date - start_date
        return f'{ delta } days'

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Your chosen habit is {self.name}, with a goal of {self.goal_nbr} {self.goal._description} for {self.duration} days, from {self.start_date} to {self.end_date}"


class Activity(models.Model):
    # name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    result_nbr = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, related_name="activity", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    habit = models.ForeignKey(
        'Habit', related_name="activity", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    @property
    def diff_between_goal_result(self):
        diff_nbr = result_nbr - self.habit.goal_nbr
        return f'{ diff_nbr }'

    class Meta:
        constraints = [models.UniqueConstraint(
            fields=['created_at', 'habit'], name='one_update_per_day'), ]

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Today you achieved: {self.result_nbr} of your {self.habit.name} {self.habit.goal_description}"
```

Comment: The exception is not here, please share the *full traceback*.

Comment: As the error says you're trying to get `goal` attribute from the object `Habit`. But `Habit` model doesn't have an attribute `goal`.  Since you haven't uploaded the whole traceback not sure where the error occurs. Check your code in either `views` or `template`

Comment: I found and corrected an unwarranted dot notation after self.goal in  {self.goal._description}. Thanks for reviewing my post.